# Single Point of Failure on scaling application across AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, scaling, mysql, high-availability

We have a **Rails-based application**, deployment infrastucture binds to **AWS**. Current schema included the following layers:

- load balancer (HaProxy)
- Rails-application (EC2) x2
- MySQLd database (EC2 master-slave)
- Redis, DelayedJob background processes
- Wowza media server (EC2)
- S3 assets storage (shared data)

There is 3 SPFs: *load balancer*, *database*, *media server*.

My questions are about redundancy, how can I reduce SPF:

1. load balancer. We have a plan to setup secondary load balancer, but domain name still the same. Is *DNS A/AAAA roundrobin failover* good solution in that case? Is AWS load balancer good to use?
2. Is *MMM* (Multi-Master Replication Manager) reliable? How does it work with Rails (read/write to independent hosts)?
3. *Wowza media server*, is there any well-known HA solutions to work with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love these questions as they always seem so simple to answer when in fact they are not.

For starters, your **BIGGEST** SPF is that everything is on Amazon. I love AWS for many reasons, but in all situations where you need real availability, you're essentially shooting yourself in the foot by relying on them 100%. So your first plan should be to distribute your services to more than 1 provider (cloud, VPS, or dedicated).

I want to aks you a question: if AWS goes down, how long does/can/will it take you to notice and then do something about it, and how quickly do you need your services to be back up and running?

The reason I ask is this: DNS load-balancing of A/AAAA records is a wonderful solution, unfortunately you can't set weights or priorities as you can with SRV/MX records. This means if AWS becomes completely unavailable, you'll have to make a DNS change real quickly to remove the IP. That **CAN** be automated if your DNS provider has an API which allows that. On the other hand, DNS caching is performed in so many places that it might not be worth making the DNS change, meaning you'll have from 50% to 100% availability if 1 IP is unavailable (assuming you have 2 A records), because some browsers are able to try the 2nd IP if the 1st doesn't work.

In my opinion, considering AWS's excellent uptime, you won't be at fault to assign 2 different IPs (on 2 different providers) to your domain. I think it's better than having 0% availability when 1 IP is down, but there's still no joy in losing 50% of your requests.

You can have 2 load-balancers on each provider, and let them forward requests to the other provider if certain instances/servers are down. In other words, you only need functional load-balancers at BOTH providers, and functional servers/instances at ONE provider. Make sure to select an alternate provider which doesn't have too much latency to AWS ;)

MMM is also a great tool, but it's not related to Rails in any way. Personally I prefer to place a load-balancer in front of all my Database servers and let them handle who gets requests etc. Since **data** on a database server is so important, it's usually better to have a human look at it and make sure everything is OK when there's a problem, as opposed to letting a tool manage its availability, configuration, etc. MMM works in many situations, perhaps you should try it and see if it answers your needs. I can't say anything bad about it.

I'm not at all familiar with Wowza media server, but a quick search explained a few things. Since Wowza uses RTSP (UDP **and** TCP), HAProxy is **NOT** a solution as it only does TCP. Keepalived on the other hand can perform UDP load-balancing (it uses IVPS/LVS). In fact, Keepalived should also be used for your database slave load-balancing if you have long queries.

One final note, there are many ways to "roll your own" AWS-like services such as S3 storage. If you want to avoid having SPFs but still need the same functionality as your AWS services, you should look into running the open source variants, such as Eucalyptus/Cloud.com/Openstack/GlusterFS. There's a lot of work involved in setting up all that stuff, but you'll be happy the day you can say: "so what if X provider is down, Y can take over".

Comment: I'm absolutely agree with you about **AWS** is the biggest **SPF**, so we don't dependent on specific AWS stuff. Our current schema is platform-agnostic. If AWS goes down, I can setup the same environment during 3 hours and 8-12hours to fetch the media-content from backups.

Comment: I wonder how Github handles the failover? I can read in a [blog](https://github.com/blog/493-github-is-moving-to-rackspace)  _On Rackspace, every piece of our infrastructure will have failover. That means two database servers, four web servers, two GitHub Pages instances, two Gem Server instances, two Archive Download instances, distributed Job runners, three pairs of file servers, and plenty more._

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion about DB scaling _Personally I prefer to place a load-balancer in front of all my Database servers and let them handle who gets requests_. Anyway it can be a SPF too.

Comment: I wonder if there scaling best practices? Can you advice well-known books, blogs?

Comment: At GitHub everything is redundant but also everything doesn't run on Amazon. There's a big difference between owning your servers and using shared resources. Always setup at least 2 load-balancers (redundancy). I use them to forward actual database requests so no need to modify code/scripts when server availability changes. For more info there's http://highscalability.com/ and http://scalabilityrules.com which show many best practices and examples from large companies such as Google and Facebook.

Comment: The book Release It! is invaluable for scaling and high availability concepts and patterns.

Comment: A word about AWS: If you're worried about AWS being a SPF, keep in mind that Amazon operates many regions (Virgina, California, Oregon, Tokyo, Europe, Singapore...) which are completely independent from each other.  Having resources in more than one AWS region is the same as having them split between different providers, from a hardware standpoint.  While the API end-points are necessarily different and you can't share AMIs across regions, you can work around that using tools.  The only sense in which all AWS regions together are a SPF, is if a failure occurs due to a design or operation flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

1) Load Balancer: Create two ha_proxy instances with your application-level load balancing knowledge and the ability to automatically create a new instance on demand.  Wire up Amazon Elastic Load Balancing in front of them with health checks to route around a single ha_proxy failure.  Dynamically mix in new ha_proxy instances when one fails.

2) Database: I don't think there's a way to handle automatic failover of your Primary in MySQL, but if you introduce a layer to read from replicas and write to the primary you may be able to keep read-only functionality up if a Primary is down.

3) Wowza: You should be able to load-balance multiple Wowza instances behind your ha_proxy layer w/ health checks so a single Wowza failure doesn't disable media streaming

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer. My questions: 1. We are going to be AWS- independent as much as possible. 2. What will be with reads if slave gone away?

Comment: 3. What independent storage do you advice? hdfs?

Comment: I respect trying to stay cloud-platform agnostic, but ELB has major advantages (using a fixed pool of IPs you can move around within EC2) over a public/permanent IP(s) for your load balancers.  Otherwise you'll have to use DNS round-robin or some less ideal solution.  Also, if one of your main load-balancer hosts fails dramatically, you'll have DNS propogation delays to get a new IP in place.  ELB with elastic IPs solves this elegantly enough to be worth using.

Comment: I agree on the fact that DNS propagation can be slow and DNS round-robin is less than ideal in most situations, but it's much MUCH better than having all your eggs in 1 basket. For the same I reason I never recommend to use the DNS servers provided by your registrar or web host. When you lose control of 1 component, the last thing you want is losing control of ALL components (ex: registrar's 20 racks get seized).

Answer (score 1):

At Scalarium we have a solution which reduces SPF dramatically, you can see a info graphic at [Rails in the Cloud](http://www.slideshare.net/jweiss/rails-in-the-cloud-4676108) on Page 12.

1. You use the Amazon Elastic Load Balancer to route between your ha_proxy instances. To have even more security you can split your application into multiple availability zones.
2. MySQL master master replication isn't the easiest thing. You can have a single master instance and have multiple slaves in multiple availability zones. Then you can support read actions even if your master has gone. I think a real master master with failover isn't possible.
3. ha_proxy should be able to load-balance your Wowza instances.

Comment: the answer almost the similiar as the first one